# CUDA - Rotating particles

Tags: cuda, gpu, particles

I'm new to CUDA and experimenting with the samples of the NVidia GPU SDK.

The goal is to rotate the spheres in the Particles example. So while the sphere is falling, it's also rotating, any pointers please?

Comment: If we're thinking about the same demo, then those particles are not spheres, but point masses part of a SPH simulation. If you want them to behave like interacting spheres, you might be better off reading up on rigid body dynamics.

Comment: thanks for quick response, in the demo they're many particles that produce spheres, they fall and splash on the bottom, maybe you're thinking of a different demo?

Comment: They are rendered as spheres yes (even as "fake" 2D ones if I'm not mistaken), but computationally they are not really. AFAIK within the simulation they are point masses which will have a certain interaction with the other particles based on their distance from each other. This distance might be visualized by the radius you see. You might have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed-particle_hydrodynamics) to see what I'm talking about.

Comment: yes it is related to fluid dynamics but I just want to rotate those spheres, question of coding/syntax/best practices, surely there's a way to rotate them but I've spent hours already, just trying to learn, this is a step.

Comment: @colinlamarre: standard SPH formulations don't include rotational degrees of freedom, only displacements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the particles sample the particles are just points with a radius.  They have no angular momentum in the simulation, because they are assumed to be point masses, not sphere masses (i.e. all of their mass is assumed to be exactly at their centers.)

If you want to do this physically, you would have to use a simplified rigid body dynamics rather than just point masses.

If you just want to visually rotate the particles (non-physically), you can do that by just applying a rotation matrix to the GL matrix stack before you draw the object that you display for each particle (you mentioned a torus).  This could be done in OpenGL, independently of the CUDA simulation code.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work with your advise and this page: http://www.fastgraph.com/makegames/3drotation/3dsrce.html